# Problems with array of images in Android

Tags: android

Im having this little issue with an array of images. Im trying to do a dymanic background on android, which will change every 8 seconds to a new picture. But when it initializes, it only changes to the first picture. Heres the code :

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
int[] p = {R.drawable.android, R.drawable.android2, R.drawable.cool};
RelativeLayout screena;
private static final long GET_DATA_INTERVAL = 8000;
int index = 0;
Handler hand = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.other_activity);
    screena = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screena);
    hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);

}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        screena.setBackgroundResource(p[index++]);
        if (index == p.length)
            hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
            index = 0;

    }


};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (index == p.length)
            screena.setBackgroundResource(p[index]);
            hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
            index = 0;

    }else{
      screena.setBackgroundResource(p[index]);
      index +=1; 
    }    
};
```

Try above code and check

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work either. It only changed to the first image, like before. I found this in the developers page.                                     public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)

Added in API level 1
Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background. This means that setbackgroundresource can only initilizite one object? If this is the case, what else can i use? Thanks

Comment: Ok then check index value for each time, I think for the first time it always set to 0. So int index = 0; change to 2 and and another 3 to 4 images in int[] p and check

Comment: Ok, i appreciate the help :)

Comment: For that you need to define index static or store in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

```
private index = 0;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override public void run() {
        screena.setBackgroundResource(p[++index % p.length]);
        hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Runnable is only called once in `onCreate`.
`index` starts at `0`, incremented in run() to value `1`, and `index == p.length` is `false` (`1 != 3`). Thus `hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);` is never called in your Runnable.

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    screena.setBackgroundResource(p[index++]);
    if (index == p.length) 
        index = 0;
    hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
    }
};
```

Or you could schedule a `TimerTask`, which would a more elegant way, imho.

```
Timer durationTimer = new Timer();
durationTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code
    }
}, 0, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exclude index=0 from your if condition scope. Hence even after increment index resets to zero. Try updating your runnable with below code

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    screena.setBackgroundResource(p[index++]);
    if (index == p.length)
    {
        hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
        index = 0;
     }
}
};
```